# managedObjectModel is nil (Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, iphonecoredatarecipes

I have this special case scenario, where in my app works perfectly fine for some time and crashes inconsistently after some time. The error that i get during the crash is **"Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model"**.

I tried debugging my app and found that the `managedObjectModel` is returning `NULL` sometimes. To add fuel to the fire, this scenario is not at all consistent. For some time the `managedObjectModel` is fine. But, suddenly it returns `NULL`...

Here is the code that I am using to create a managed object model.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel 
{
    if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel_;
    }
    NSBundle *newBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"dataBundle" withExtension:@"bundle"]];   
    NSString *modelPath = [newBundle pathForResource:@"DataHouse" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
    managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSLog(@"managedObjectModel_ %@", [managedObjectModel_ entities]);

    return managedObjectModel_;
}
```

As you can see above, due to some special requirements, I have placed my .**xcdataModeld** file in a **separate bundle** and referencing it from there. I got struck and need some help.... Thanks

Comment: How is the variable managedObjectModel_ declared?  as an iVar? Where is it retained?  This smells like a memory problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint Ray.. The actual problem turned out be due to memory issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you never reset `managedObjectModel_` to `nil`. Just search your source code for "`managedObjectModel_ =`", the only result should be in the `managedObjectModel` code you posted.

Secondly, make sure that `managedObjectModel_` is either inaccessible from outside or (if you expose `managedObjectModel` as a property) readonly.

Thirdly, make sure there's one and only one instance of the class managing the Core Data stack. If it's the `UIApplication` delegate initialized in the main window nib, you shouldn't create it programmatically. If it's a singleton, check if there's really a single instance of it.

When you are absolutely sure everything is right, it's time to go digging deeper. You can try setting a watchpoint in GDB to `managedObjectModel_`.

The worst thing possibly going on in your code is a kind of `memset`/`memmove` operations which happen to overwrite memory occupied by your Core Data stack manager. But this sort of error is too random to always hit a given memory address, so I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: The problem turned out to be due to memory issues. I was not releasing the objects of coredata due to which there are some memory leaks. I rectified the issues and no more problems now :). But thank you so much for the valuable information dude... Accepted your answer.. :)

Comment: I tried to used to confirm the first point and nothing was found! What  can I do about that?