# Core Data, mom vs momd extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, bundle

**mom vs momd extension**

In my project I was using `momd` extension to get `.xcdatamodel` from the bundle and it was working fine one month ago but today every time I try to access `Core data` objects it started crashing saying `modelURL` nil in below code

```
private lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.modelName, withExtension: "momd”) else {
            fatalError("Unable to Find Data Model URL")
        }

        guard let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Unable to Load Data Model")
        }

        return managedObjectModel
}()
```

So after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212313/managedobjectmodel-is-nil-cannot-create-an-nspersistentstorecoordinator-with-a) question, In that question, he was using `mom` as an extension so I changed the above code to `mom` and now its working fine but that was a 6-year-old question. So I can’t able to figure it out that how suddenly this becomes a problem in my project.
Even apple official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/making_core_data_your_model_layer) use `momd` as an extension.

And also how to make sure which will always work and use that only and also in that question @yuji pointed out that

> To get the .mom(d) file is not exactly the recommended way.
>   Use mergedModelFromBundles instead

So how exactly this work with single .xcdatamodel

Comment: modelUrl is nil?

Comment: Have you considered using [NSPersistenContainer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer) instead?

Comment: I have more than one context, and it was confusing to handle them using apple default persistentContainer implementation, it does simplify, but in commets they write /*This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail. */

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new model, by default you get two files: MyDataModel.momd and a nested MyDataModel.mom.

When you add a version, another mom file is created and added to the momd bundle.

When you create an NSManagedObjectModel instance by pointing to the momd file, the current version (as selected in the inspector File pane) will be used. Point to the mom file if you need to access an earlier version of the model, such as when migrating your model.